# How to customize tokenizer with complex token_match?

Tags: python, spacy

I'm using `spacy` to do some customized tokenizer. I want to take the API name as one `token`. Such as `srcs[offset].remaining()` in sentence:

`Up to the first srcs[offset].remaining() bytes of this sequence are written from buffer srcs[offset].`

I have added a *token_match* to *tokenizer*, however it was overridden by suffixes.

The code is shown below:

```py
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

def customize_tokenizer_api_name_recognition(nlp):
    # add api_name regex, such aaa.bbb(cccc) or aaa[bbb].ccc(ddd)
    api_name_match = re.compile("(\w+(\[[\w+-]+\])?\.)+\w+\(.*?\)", re.UNICODE).match
    nlp.tokenizer.token_match = api_name_match

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    customize_tokenizer_api_name_recognition(nlp)
    sentence = "Up to the first srcs[offset].remaining() bytes of this sequence are written from buffer srcs[offset]."
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    print([token.text for token in doc])
    # output:  ['Up', 'to', 'the', 'first', 'srcs[offset].remaining', '(', ')', 'bytes', 'of', 'this', 'sequence', 'are', 'written', 'from', 'buffer', 'srcs[offset', ']', '.']
    # expected output: ['Up', 'to', 'the', 'first', 'srcs[offset].remaining()', 'bytes', 'of', 'this', 'sequence', 'are', 'written', 'from', 'buffer', 'srcs[offset', ']', '.']
```

I have seen some related issues [#4573](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4573), [#4645](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4645) and [the doc](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers). However all the examples are simple regex, and they were solved by removing some prefixes_search. what about the complex regex? How to solve this type of problem?

ps: I used to using `doc.retokenize()` to implement it. Can the problem be solved more elegantly by customizing the tokenizer?

*Environment*

- Operating System: Win 10
- Python Version Used: python 3.7.3
- spaCy Version Used: spacy 2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokenizer solution would the same as #4573, except that you customize the suffixes. It's not a great solution, though, because then `)` isn't a suffix anywhere.

I think the solution with `doc.retokenize()` is better for v2.2. You can do it in a small custom pipeline component that's added to the beginning of the pipeline.

(It might be better to have two `token_match` options, one with prefixes and suffixes and one without, but it's not great to make the tokenizer options more complicated than they already are, either.)